# How to find out how many lines of text is there in Android textview

Tags: android, textview, tablelayout, tablerow

I am using a Tablelayout as below:

```
<TableLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:stretchColumns="1" >

<TableRow android:layout_marginTop="2dp">
<TextView android:text="Email Id" android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" android:textStyle="bold"
android:textSize="16sp" android:textColor="#000000"
android:layout_weight="2" 
android:background="#e0f7fd"/>

<TextView  android:text="abcedfgh.jklmn@gmail.com"
android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:layout_weight="2" android:textSize="15sp"
android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"/>
</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Text "abcedfgh.jklmn@gmail.com" is coming in multiple lines. I have to set background color to textview "Email Id" depending on the number of lines "abcedfgh.jklmn@gmail.com" text covers.

For example:
If text "abcedfgh.jklmn@gmail.com" comes in two lines, I have to set background color to textview "Email Id" of height two lines.

Comment: can't directly set color to your textview?

Comment: @user2740599 Please accept or comment if the answer helps you.

Answer (score 2):

There is an option to find out the line count of the `TextView`

```
int lineCount = textView.getLineCount();
```

Say for ex :

Use Runnable thread to avoid exception.

```
YourTextView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int totalLine    = YourTextView.getLineCount();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How can I set background to the "Email Id" text view. "Email Id" text view background color should cover the number of lines "android:text="abcedfgh.jklmn@gmail.com"" text covers?

Comment: Are you going to set different colors based on line count?

Answer (score 1):

```
TextView text = (TextView)findViewByID(R.id.text);
int lineCount = text.getLineCount();
```

This might help you..